# Remove parent margin for a responsive image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By using **Bootstrap**, I designed a page as follows:

[image: original]

Now, I'd like to:

1. remove left and right margins *only* for the image (that uses `.img-resposive` as class);
2. keep the image as responsive, but increasing its width according to `.jumbotron` size.

To be clear, the desired result is shown below:

[image: desired]

How can I do that?

Regards, V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative margins on a wrapper for this image :

```
.img-responsive-parent {
    margin: 0 -60px;
}
```

And html :

```
<div class="img-responsive-parent">
    <img class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't enough. Negative margins just shift the image, but the size remains the same.

Comment: Woops ok I thought it was the parent